# Xcode8 can not import vendor framework header files?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, pch

After I updated my `Xcode` to`Xcode 8`.

I found out that if I import vendor framework header files in `.pch` file. there will be a error. `'xxx' .h file not Found`

Such as: 
I want to import a framework named Umeng's header file.
So I write the codes below to my `XXX-prefix.pch`

```
#import <UMMobClick/MobClick.h>
```

But Error `UMMobClick/MobClick.h file not found` appeared.

Any constriction of Xcode that prohibit importing vendor framework header files in `.pch` file?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a legacy Xcode project that used a .pch file -- the file was being ignored.

The fix was in build settings, where the original path to this file assumed it began at the project root:

```
SharkAlert/SharkAlert-Prefix.pch
```

Xcode 8 apparently requires an explicit reference to the starting point

```
$(SRCROOT)/SharkAlert/SharkAlert-Prefix.pch
```

Now the project builds as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If this file you are used to bridge OC and Swift，now you should creat a new .header file and Move All Header file Name inside file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Changing `#import <Framework/Framework.h>` to `@import Framework;` fixed it for me.